# dynamically loading and unloading Javascript files within a Windows Script File (WSF)

Tags: javascript, windows-scripting, wsh

I would like to be able to dynamically load a Javascript file within a WSF. There is no DOM I don't think, but if there were, I could try something like:

```
function addJavascriptFile(filename) {
    var file = document.createElement('script')
    file.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
    file.setAttribute("src", filename)
}
```

After running a function, I could unload with something like:

```
 function removeJavascriptFile(filename) {
 var all = document.getElementsByTagName("script")
 for (var i = all.length; i >= 0; i--) {
     if (all[i] && all[i].getAttribute("src") != null && all[i].getAttribute("src").indexOf(filename) != -1)
         all[i].parentNode.removeChild(all[i])
     }
 }
```

Does anyone know if there is something equivalent without using the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, but hopefully someone will come by with a better solution. I'll answer my own question in case someone comes across the same problem.

Given there is no DOM, I simply `eval(javascriptFileContents)` the file contents and then call the function literal directly. For example, if I have a file `wombat.js` with a `function (logger) {...` inside:

```
var logger = ...
var fn = eval(wombatJsContents);
fn(logger);
```

It's not pretty and probably a little dangerous, but it works. I'm hopeful that someone will find a better way. In the mean time...